# Why doesn't this Python code give me a solution even with a large range?

Tags: python

Below is the problem I'm trying to solve:

*2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?*

It is the 5th problem from Project Euler (http://projecteuler.net/problem=5). I wrote a code in Python to find out the number, but I'm unable to obtain a solution.

My code is:

```
def smallestNumber():
 smallest=0 ## Initializing the smallest number
 end=False ## Initializing the break condition for lower level For loop
 found=False ## Initializing the break condition for upper level For loop
 for i in range(21,10000000): ## Upper level for loop
    if i==10000000 and found==False: break ## This will break upper loop when range is satisfied
    for k in range(1,20): ## Lower level for loop
        if end==True: break ## This will break lower loop when range is satisfied
        if i%k==0: ## If condition to check whether current i value is divisible evenly by current k value
            if k==20: ## If k==20, this will make smallest equal to current i value and make both break conditions True
                smallest=i
                end=True
                found=True
            k=k+1
        else: ## if not divisible, this will increment upper level loop
            break
            i=i+1

 if found==False: print 'No value exists in this range'
 else: return smallest
```

(I'm new to stackoverflow and was unable to paste the actual code without messing up the formatting. I apologize for any inconvenience due to that).

I keep getting the output 'No value exists in this range' regardless of how big I make my range. I'm guessing that although my logic is alright, I have messed up the code somewhere since I'm a Python beginner.

It'd be great if someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with your code, not the least of which being that the formating makes it nearly unreadable. Please fix your indentation.

Comment: You may want to google for "least common multiple".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some things that are wrong:

1. The answer is greater than your upper limit of 10000000
2. Your should use `xrange` in Python 2, otherwise you'll have memory errors if you increase the upper limit
3. If you want all of the numbers from 1 to 20, you should use `range(1, 21)`
4. You should not manually increase loop counters, `range` or `xrange` do it for you

Comment: Thank you. I made all the changes in my code, plus a few more, and it gives me the answer in 1.283E-06 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you need is LCM of the numbers from 1 to 20. You can find better ways to find LCM than the one you've implemented in this code.

Next, there are a few mistakes here. I've edited your code to illustrate. Please see my code bellow, this shows the changes I had to make in order to make your code produce the correct result for finding the smallest number divisible by all numbers from 1 to 10:

```
def smallestNumber():
smallest=0 
end=False 
found=False
for i in range(21,1000000):
    if found==True: break # This will break upper loop when number is found
    for k in range(1,11): # the range is up to 11 here because we need to check numbers 1-10
        if end==True: break 
        if i%k==0:
            if k==10: ## 
                smallest=i
                end=True
                found=True
            #k=k+1 # not necessary
        else:
            break
            #i=i+1 # not necessary

if found==False: print 'No value exists in this range'
else: return smallest
```

As you can see, I had to comment out lines like `i=i+1` because that is already being taken care of by using `for i in range(21,10000000)`.
You would also notice that I had to change `if i==10000000 and found==False: break` to `if found==True: break` because checking for i=10000000 is not necessary and you should actually stop searching when your found is true. And that was the real bug in your code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. After editing the code as per your suggestions, it was running fine for range(1,11) but was taking too much time for range(1,21). I guessed that it was not going to end any time soon and exited the program. I made a few changes after that to optimize the code and it gave me the solution in less than 1/10th of a second.